# Passing data between two view controllers are not working

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to pass some data between two view controllers, but it doesn't work..

This is the data  i am trying to pass(these has items from parse.com - the same code is in both view controllers):

```
var userFile = [PFFile]()
var createdAt = [NSDate]()
var objID = [String]()
```

This is the button for open the view controller(inside the first view controller i am trying to send data FROM):

```
@IBAction func openButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        let modalVC = ModalViewController(nibName: "ModalViewController", bundle: nil)
        modalVC.userFile = self.userFile
        modalVC.createdAt = self.createdAt
        modalVC.objID = self.objID

        print("USERFILE: \(modalVC.userFile.count)")
        presentViewController(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The view controller is a `ModalViewController.xib` connected to `ViewStoryModalViewController.swift`

This is the viewDidLoad in the view controller i am trying to send data TO:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("USERFILECOUNT: \(self.userFile.count)")
    }
```

My problem is that this is the messages i get in xCode output:
[image]

What might be wrong here? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see the full code for both view controllers. It is hard to tell what `self.userFile` in the first one contains, for example.

Comment: @grez It does contains an object. I have checked using `print` after making a query.

Answer (score 0):

xCode output tells that an array self.userFile contains zero elements, It doesn't mean that it is passed wrong. It is just empty.

```
print("USERFILECOUNT: \(self.userFile.count)")
```

Check if it is empty before passing it to modal vc.

Comment: It's not empty before passing it.

Comment: If your ModalViewController.xib connected with ViewStoryModalViewController.swift, you should initialize it this way: let modalVC = ViewStoryModalViewController(nibName: "ModalViewController", bundle: nil)

Comment: I get this error: `Use of unresolved identifier "ViewStoryModalViewController"`. This is my controller: http://s32.postimg.org/rmrfuw91h/Screen_Shot_2016_05_06_at_13_52_48.png - And inside the class: `class ModalViewController: UIViewController`

Comment: What class is declared inside it?

Comment: Inside the `ViewStoryModalViewController.swift` it says: `class ModalViewController: UIViewController {`

Comment: Then this line is right: let modalVC = ModalViewController(nibName: "ModalViewController", bundle: nil)

Comment: Can you post a print of  modalVC variable? And one more: do other variables like createdAt & objID pass correct?

Comment: Sorry my bad, inside the `ViewStoryModalViewController.swift` it says: `class ViewStoryModalViewController: UIViewController {`

Comment: None of the variables get passed correctly.. But is it possible to store the variables inside another view controller, ex: `Variables.swift` and get the from there after the segue, or?

Comment: Then it should be as I wrote above  let modalVC = ViewStoryModalViewController(nibName: "ModalViewController", bundle: nil), try ti fix Use of unresolved identifier issue by making ViewStoryModalViewController class  public..

Comment: It's weird, i still get this in the output: http://s32.postimg.org/3ku51dmbp/Screen_Shot_2016_05_06_at_14_26_22.png

Comment: What class is declared in ModalViewController.xib? Can you post a picture?

Comment: That is depending on what i choose on the left side.. Look here: 1: http://s32.postimg.org/70svgbio5/Screen_Shot_2016_05_06_at_14_43_35.png 2: http://s32.postimg.org/dq40a2tdx/Screen_Shot_2016_05_06_at_14_44_05.png

Comment: In class field (first image) replace ModalViewController with ViewStoryModalViewController

Comment: Tried that and still not working: http://s32.postimg.org/ez2ysqc1x/Screen_Shot_2016_05_07_at_01_49_15.png and output: http://s32.postimg.org/wea5xps3p/Screen_Shot_2016_05_07_at_01_50_40.png - But can i try storing the data inside another ViewController.swift file and take it from that after the viewDidLoad? Or will that now work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
You first need to present after that try to set variable.

```
IBAction func openButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        let modalVC = ModalViewController(nibName: "ModalViewController", bundle: nil)
      print("USERFILE: \(modalVC.userFile.count)")
        presentViewController(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        modalVC.userFile = self.userFile
        modalVC.createdAt = self.createdAt
        modalVC.objID = self.objID
    }
```

Comment: Tried this, and still get 0 items.